# What is the recommended way to increment date in JAVA?

Tags: java

I am using the `Calendar` class to increment a date. However, all I see for any month is that it is incrementing until the 31st day of that month, regardless of the month being February or not.

Below is the code I am using now:

```
long curDayDate = 1524787200;  // April, 27th, 2018

Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(curDayDate*1000);
LocalDateTime ldt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("GMT")).toLocalDateTime();

int gYear   = ldt.getYear();
int gMonth  = ldt.getMonthValue();
int gDay    = ldt.getDayOfMonth();

Calendar Cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Cal.set(gYear, gMonth, gDay);

for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

    // Next day
    Cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    System.out.println("Next Year = " + Cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + ", Next Month = " + Cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + ", Next Date = " + Cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
}
```

The above code goes until the 31st of April, even though there is no 31st day for the month of April.

Comment: @AndyTurner Which one to use then? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Don't use `Calendar`*. It is part of a raft of poorly-designed date/time APIs that were introduced in early versions of Java (`Calendar` was introduced in JDK 1.1), and supplanted by the `java.time` package introduced in Java 8.

If you want to add a day to a `LocalDateTime`, use [`plusDays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#plusDays-long-).

Comment: Excellent. It worked like a charm with LocalDateTime. Thank you. Was frustrated for a while looking at it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @scope I rejected your edit, because I really did mean "raft" (as in a lot, but also vaguely implying some sort of cobbling-together), rather than "draft" (as in a preliminary or proposed version).